# I Get Always Same Value When I Click the Button andSend It to the Next Page With Session Inside the Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, eval

On the homepage of the website I made, I pull the products from the database with the repeater and eval as below:

```
<div class="col-md-12 grid-gallery overflow-hidden">
    <div class="tab-content">
        <ul class="grid masonry-items">
            <asp:Repeater ID="RptrProductInfo" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDtSourceProductInfo">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <li class="<%#Eval("productcategory") %>">
                        <figure>
                            <div class="gallery-img"><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click"><img src="<%#Eval("prouctimage") %>" alt="" /></asp:LinkButton></div>
                            <figcaption>
                                <asp:Label ID="LblProductID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("productid") %>'></asp:Label>
                                <h3><%#Eval("productname") %></h3>
                                <p>Ürün hakkında detaylı bilgi için tıklayınız.</p>
                            </figcaption>
                        </figure>
                    </li>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDtSourceProductInfo" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:aytasarimConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [productid], [productname], [productcategory], [productimage] FROM [product]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to do is: When the user clicks on the product, it will transfer the product's id to the next page with the session and list the related product id and other properties of the product (product image, description, price etc.). But clicking on which product I click will only receive the first product id is id number 1. For example I click third product, then same id info appears on the other page (ID 1). I always get ID 1 whatever I click. My aspx.cs code as below:

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (RepeaterItem item in RptrProductInfo.Items)
    {
        Label lblName = (Label)item.FindControl("LblProductID");
        if (lblName != null)
        {
            string mesaj = "";
            DataRow drLogin = function.GetDataRow("SELECT productid FROM product WHERE productid='" + lblName.Text + "'");
            if(drLogin == null)
            {
                mesaj = "<script>alert('Error!');</script>";
                Response.Write(mesaj);
            }
            else
            {
                Session["productid"] = drLogin["productid"].ToString();
                Response.Redirect("product.aspx");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my product.aspx page:

```
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 zoom-gallery sm-margin-bottom-ten">
                        <a href="<%#Eval("productimage") %>"><img src="<%#Eval("productimage") %>" alt=""/></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-md-offset-1">
                        <span class="product-name-details text-uppercase font-weight-600 letter-spacing-2 black-text"><%#Eval("productname") %></span>
                        <p class="text-uppercase letter-spacing-2 margin-two">Stok Durumu: <%#Eval("stock") %></p>
                        <div class="separator-line bg-black no-margin-lr margin-five"></div>
                        <p><%#Eval("description") %></p>
                        <span class="price black-text title-small"><%#Eval("price") %></span>
                        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 no-padding margin-five">
                            <a class="highlight-button-dark btn btn-medium button" href="shop-cart.html"><i class="icon-basket"></i> Add To Cart</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:aytasarimConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [productid], [productname], [stock], [description], [price], [productimage] FROM [product] WHERE ([productid] = @productid)">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:SessionParameter Name="productid" SessionField="productid" Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Could you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45410600/edit) to clarify the title so it describes your problem, instead of just saying 'I have a problem all the time'? That will encourage more people to read and answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one bucle in the click event that makes that it takes the first product, you should take the value from sender object.

You can add a `CommandArgument="<%#Eval("productid") %>"`  in the link button and get it in the click event

```
LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)(sender);
    string productid = btn.CommandArgument;
```

Something like that could be the Repeater:

```
<div class="col-md-12 grid-gallery overflow-hidden">
    <div class="tab-content">
        <ul class="grid masonry-items">
            <asp:Repeater ID="RptrProductInfo" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDtSourceProductInfo">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <li class="<%#Eval("productcategory") %>">
                        <figure>
                            <div class="gallery-img"><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click" CommandArgument="<%#Eval("productid")%>"><img src="<%#Eval("prouctimage") %>" alt="" /></asp:LinkButton></div>
                            <figcaption>
                                <asp:Label ID="LblProductID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("productid") %>'></asp:Label>
                                <h3><%#Eval("productname") %></h3>
                                <p>Ürün hakkında detaylı bilgi için tıklayınız.</p>
                            </figcaption>
                        </figure>
                    </li>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDtSourceProductInfo" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:aytasarimConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [productid], [productname], [productcategory], [productimage] FROM [product]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The code behind should be something like :

```
    protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)(sender);
        string productid = btn.CommandArgument;
        Session["productid"] = productid;
        Response.Redirect("product.aspx");
}
```

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: You can add a CommandArgument="<%#Eval("productid") %>"  in the link button and get it in the click event 

LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)(sender);
    string productid = btn.CommandArgument;

Comment: I wrote the code at the top of the click event what you said, same after (foreach code). But it didn't work. Where could i have done wrong?